# How to implement a Placeholder in an Editor in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have read that the Editor control doesn't have a placeholder, so I have been trying to do a workaround without success. I know that the Entry control has a Placeholder, but I need multiline field as I am going to use it as a field where users can write a comment, and not just a single line.

This is my approach:

I have tried to put an Editor and a Label into a Grid control, with the Label being on top of the Editor. The Editor's `InputTransparent` flag is set to `true`. Then I just toggle the `IsVisible` property of the label depending on the whether the `Editor` has text or not. However, the problem is that I am using the MVVM pattern, so I don't know how to control the `TextChanged` event in the `ViewModel`. I have also tried to code behind, but the name of the Label can't be found.

This is my XAML code - Have only posted the relevant code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
  <Editor Text="{Binding UserComment, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="EditorTextChanged"                                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
  <Label x:Name="PlaceholderLabel" Text="Write a comment" InputTransparent="True"                                             HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
  </Grid>
```

For now, in the code-behind, I only have the `EditorTextChanged` event, which works fine, but it can't find `PlaceholderLabel`. I have binded the whole View to my ViewModel, is that the reason? How would approach it, if you had to follow the MVVM pattern?

It's worth mentioning that I have tried [this](https://xamarinexplorer.com/2017/11/25/adding-placeholder-to-editor/) approach. However, it didn't work as expected. The Placeholder would only appear when I clicked on the Editor and then unclicked it. It should appear in the beginning as on Facebook.

**EDIT**

This is the whole XAML code:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:TeamAlignmentConverter x:Key="teamConverter"/>
            <local:ImageAlignmentConverter x:Key="imageConverter"/>
            <local:BooleanReverser x:Key="booleanReverser"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="5">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.BindingContext>
                    <viewModel:MatchPageVM/>
                </Grid.BindingContext>

                <Grid BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="0" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.8*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Teams}" FontSize="26" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <Image Source="notificationsbell.png" Margin="25,10,0,0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Score}" FontSize="80" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Label Text="Live" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
                </Grid>


            </Grid>
            <Grid RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.BindingContext>
                    <viewModel:MatchPageVM/>
                </Grid.BindingContext>
                <cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionList}">
                    <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <flv:FlowListView x:Name="flowListView" FlowColumnCount="1" Grid.Row="0"
                                  SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True"  IsVisible="{Binding ListSwitch}"
                                  FlowItemsSource="{Binding CollectionList}" BackgroundColor="White" >
                                    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.005*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding PlayerName}" Grid.Column="{Binding Team}" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="{Binding Team, Converter={StaticResource teamConverter}}"/>
                                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{Binding Team, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="20" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                                </flv:FlowListView>

                                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <flv:FlowListView x:Name="flowListView2" FlowColumnCount="1" BackgroundColor="White"
                                  HasUnevenRows="True" HeightRequest="180" IsVisible="{Binding ListSwitch, Converter={StaticResource booleanReverser}}" Grid.Row="0"
                                  FlowItemsSource="{Binding CollectionList}" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Black">
                                        <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid RowSpacing="5">
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding UserName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="0,10,0,5" />
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding UserComment}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                                    </flv:FlowListView>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="{Binding ListSwitch, Converter={StaticResource booleanReverser}}">
                                        <Editor Text="{Binding UserComment, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Editor.BindingContext>
                                                <viewModel:MatchPageVM/>
                                            </Editor.BindingContext>
                                        </Editor>
                                        <Label Text="Skriv en kommentar" 
                                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding LabelIsVisible}" InputTransparent="True">
                                            <Label.BindingContext>
                                                <viewModel:MatchPageVM/>
                                            </Label.BindingContext>
                                        </Label>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </cv:CarouselView>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: I've done your approach successfully in MVVM. you can convert any event to command to be run from viewmodel, for this you can use Behaviors NuGet.

Comment: @Vahid Can you show how? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your own mentioned approach that does work:

```
<AbsoluteLayout
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Editor
                    Text="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, WidthProportional"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1.01,100">
                </Editor>
                <Label Text="MyPlaceHolder" IsVisible="{Binding IsAddrerssPlaceHolderVisible}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5, 1, 0.5" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" InputTransparent="True"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Here is Viewmodel part:

```
public bool IsAddrerssPlaceHolderVisible
        {
            get => _isAddrerssPlaceHolderVisible;
            set
            {
                _isAddrerssPlaceHolderVisible= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

public string Address
        {
            get => _address;
            set
            {
                _address = value;
                if (value.Length > 0)
                {
                    IsAddrerssPlaceHolderVisible= false;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsAddrerssPlaceHolderVisible= true;
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

It doesn't even need anything else which I previously mentioned by mistake! It works as simple as that :D

Comment: I have tried this, but something is wrong in my code. For some reason it doesn't make the Label invisible even though when it goes through IsAddrerssPlaceHolderVisible= false;. Have tested with a breakpoint

Comment: That's exactly what I used in my own project and it works like a charm. have you put PropertyChanged notifier event inside IsAddrerssPlaceHolderVisible's setter as in code above it is "RaisePropertyChanged()"?

Comment: Please show me your IsAddrerssPlaceHolderVisible property.

Comment: Yes, here: `private bool _labelIsVisible { get; set; } = true;
        public bool LabelIsVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return _labelIsVisible;
            }
            set
            {
                _labelIsVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LabelIsVisible));
            }
        }`

Comment: I have also tried to print LabelIsVisible when it's set to false in the code. It says false, but it doesn't make it invisible.

Comment: Have also tried to bind the text and put an empty string instead when the inputtext > 0. In the console it says that the text is empty, but the label doesn't change. Weird

Comment: Though it's harder to figure it out without seeing your codes, but the only thing that is in my mind at the moment is there must be a problem with binding context of label maybe!

Comment: Can you please share more from your XAML?

Comment: Have posted the whole XAML class. Please see the OP :)

Comment: Here are some debugging options could help:
- Put a breakpoint in the setter of UserComment property(after the line when LabelIsVisibleis set) and while this breakpoint is hit hover your mouse over LabelIsVisible in XAMl, check what that shows(maybe this is a Resharper feature).

Comment: - Check BindingContext of Label in the setter of UserComment. You can do it for example by checking Label's BindingContext property or even Implement Label's BindingContextChanged event and check its value and whether, In both cases there must be LabelIsVisibleis property correctly reflecting its value.
And finally as the last resort you could provide us with a link to your whole project or at least a minimum operable one.

Comment: Have tried your first suggestion: When I hover over it gives me "false", which is correct. However, the list on UI doesn't update. Regarding the BindingContext, I have set that to the ViewModel

Comment: Let's stick to the last resort!

Comment: The problem is fixed. The problem was the bindingcontext of the parrent Grid.

Comment: I'm glad you could solve it eventually. Yeah the bindingContext was suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a Custom Renderer, you see since Xamarin.Forms is just another level from the native elements, you can "access" the native elements using a CustomRenderer:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

You can create the base Custom Editor:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EditorWithPlaceholder
{
    public class PlaceholderEditor : Editor
    {
        public static BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty
            = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Placeholder), typeof(string), typeof(PlaceholderEditor));

        public static BindableProperty PlaceholderColorProperty
            = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceholderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(PlaceholderEditor), Color.Gray);

        public string Placeholder
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(PlaceholderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value); }
        }

        public Color PlaceholderColor
        {
            get { return (Color) GetValue(PlaceholderColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceholderColorProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Renderers on each platform:

Android:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PlaceholderEditor), typeof(PlaceholderEditorRenderer))]
namespace EditorWithPlaceholder.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class PlacehoderEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Element == null)
                return;

            var element = (PlaceholderEditor) Element;

            Control.Hint = element.Placeholder;
            Control.SetHintTextColor(element.PlaceholderColor.ToAndroid());
        }
    }
}
```

iOS:

```
using System;
using Cirrious.FluentLayouts.Touch;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PlaceholderEditor), typeof(PlaceholderEditorRenderer))]
namespace EditorWithPlaceholder.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class PlaceholderEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        private UILabel _placeholderLabel;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Element == null)
                return;

            CreatePlaceholderLabel((PlaceholderEditor) Element, Control);

            Control.Ended += OnEnded;
            Control.TextChanged += OnChanged;
        }

        private void CreatePlaceholderLabel(PlaceholderEditor element, UITextView parent)
        {
            _placeholderLabel = new UILabel
            {
                Text = element.Placeholder,
                TextColor = element.PlaceholderColor.ToUIColor(),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
                Font = UIFont.FromName(element.FontFamily, (nfloat)element.FontSize)
            };
            _placeholderLabel.SizeToFit();

            parent.AddSubview(_placeholderLabel);

            parent.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
            parent.AddConstraints(
                _placeholderLabel.AtLeftOf(parent, 7),
                _placeholderLabel.WithSameCenterY(parent)
            );
            parent.LayoutIfNeeded();

            _placeholderLabel.Hidden = parent.HasText;
        }

        private void OnEnded(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (!((UITextView) sender).HasText && _placeholderLabel != null)
                _placeholderLabel.Hidden = false;
        }

        private void OnChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (_placeholderLabel != null)
                _placeholderLabel.Hidden = ((UITextView) sender).HasText;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Control.Ended -= OnEnded;
                Control.Changed -= OnChanged;

                _placeholderLabel?.Dispose();
                _placeholderLabel = null;
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this information helps.

For reference:
https://solidbrain.com/2017/07/10/placeholder-text-in-xamarin-forms-editor/